# All items in list duplicated when saved to text file - Python

Tags: python, list, io

I have a function which takes a list, converts it to a string, and outputs it to a .txt file, but when I check the text file it has doubled each entry. I have searched for an answer but cannot find one, apologies if this has been asked before. 
My code:

```
workers = ["John","Mark"]

# Prints list of employees to file
def printAllWorkers():
    strList = str(workers).strip('[]')
    with open('EmployeeList.txt','w') as file:
        for item in workers:
            file.write(strList)
```

So the list should show 'John', 'Mark', but instead shows 'John', 'Mark', 'John', 'Mark'

I either need a way to only output the list once (preferred) or take the text file and remove any duplicates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write your created string twice. Don't iterate over the workers and write the whole output for each worker. Do it only once:

```
def printAllWorkers():
    strList = str(workers).strip('[]')
    with open('EmployeeList.txt','w') as file:
        file.write(strList)
```

File content:

```
'John', 'Mark'
```

Comment: Exacly what I was looking for, and I see where I went wrong! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you are writing the whole list `strList` at each iteration, you could fix it as follows:

```
workers = ["John","Mark"]

# Prints list of employees to file
def printAllWorkers():
    with open('EmployeeList.txt','w') as file:
        file.write(', '.join(workers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the write command out of the for loop, its showing up twice because you have it in a loop that has 2 entries

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're telling the program in the last line to write the list to the file once per item. Replace strlist in file.write(strlist) with item, and it will work as expected.

To be clear your last line needs to be file.write(item)

Comment: Not quite, because the OP wants a comma and a space between the items.

Comment: Welp, missed that. Shows that I still have much to learn. Thankfully others provided more comprehensive answers. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the for loop, as you are iterated over ever element in the **workers** list, 2 elements, and getting the **strList** outputted twice.

```
workers = ["John","Mark"]

# Prints list of employees to file
def printAllWorkers():
    strList = str(workers).strip('[]')
    with open('EmployeeList.txt','w') as file:
        file.write(strList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with the same code but replace  `file.write(strList)` with  `file.write(item)`. You are iterating over, but writing the list instead of iterated value.

Either go with this:

```
workers = ["John","Mark"]

    def printAllWorkers():
        #strList = str(workers).strip('[]')
        with open('EmployeeList.txt','w') as file:
            for item in workers:
                file.write(item)
```